Update one form from another
I can't update one form from another; in detail:
I create a form programmatically using a form template with
Dim FormVendor As New FormTempSint
in this form there are a label counter and a datagridview with the data taken from a DB with a query. With doubleclick on a row of the datagridview I open another form for the details also programmatically  with
Dim FormVendorDetail As New FormTempDetail
From this form I modify the vendor values ​​and when saving with the Save button I would like to update the datagridview of the first form before closing the second. I can't use the showdialog method because the second window can't be modal.
How can I update FormVendor controls from FormVendorDetail?

This question is similar to: Send data within Child Forms. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You simply need to handle the FormClosed event of the second form in the first form. When the event is raised, you know the form has closed so you can get whatever data you need from it by getting one or more properties and/or calling one or more methods, exactly like you get data out of any object.

After you create an instance of the second form, but before you show it to the user, you give it a reference to the instance of the first form it can use.

Just like any other object, handle the appropriate event to be notified when the thing of interest happens and then get the data of interest from properties and/or methods.
Private Sub OpenOtherForm()
    Dim frm As New SomeOtherForm

    'Attach the handler method to the event.
    AddHandler frm.FormClosed, AddressOf SomeOtherFormClosed

    frm.Open()
End Sub

Private Sub SomeOtherFormClosed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim frm = DirectCast(sender, SomeOtherForm)

    'Detach the handler method from the event.
    RemoveHandler frm.FormClosed, AddressOf SomeOtherFormClosed

    'Use whatever properties and/or methods you need to get the data you need.
    Dim data = frm.GetTheData()

    'Use data here.
End Sub

